# ByRef in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have written the following code in VB.NET:

```
  Dim obj As Object
    obj = "00"
    Test(obj)
    MsgBox(obj)


Private Sub Test(ByRef num As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub Test(ByVal num As Integer)

End Sub
```

When the value "00" is passed "ByRef" in the method "Test" it converts to 0. But if the value "00" is passed "ByVal" it keeps the same value as "00". How the passed value is being converted only depending of the signature?
In VB6 although the default passing type is "ByRef", still the same code keeps the same value("00")

Could anybody explain the reason behind this contradictory behaviour in VB6 and VB.NET?

Comment: You are passing a string to a function that expect an integer. By default, integers don't have trailling "0" when converted to strings.

Comment: But the same thing works if it is passed ByVal

Comment: I couldn't replicate your test.  In both cases num was an integer with a value of 0.  Also, Option Strict must be off for this to compile, not a good idea IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

The way you are doing it, the ByRef changes the type of the object from string to integer. By default, integer do not have trailling "0" when covnerted to strings.

This example below might help you understand what is hapenning.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim o1 As Object = "00"
    Dim o2 As Object = "00"

    Console.WriteLine(o1.GetType().ToString())
    Test1(o1)
    Console.WriteLine(o1.GetType().ToString())

    Console.WriteLine(o2.GetType().ToString())
    Test2(o2)
    Console.WriteLine(o2.GetType().ToString())

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Sub Test1(ByVal num As Integer)

End Sub

Sub Test2(ByRef num As Integer)

End Sub
```

Output

```
System.String
System.String
System.String
System.Int32
```

I suggest you always turn **Option Strict On**, this will remove a lot of confusion.

Comment: +1 for Option Strict.  Leaving Option Strict Off tends to lead to a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1):

The object is of type System.String.  It cannot be passed ByRef to a method, it is of the wrong type.  So the compiler has to work around it and rewrites the code:

```
Dim obj As Object
obj = "00"
Dim $temp As Integer
$temp = CInt(obj)
Test($temp)
obj = $temp                 '' <=== Here
MsgBox(obj)
```

The indicated statement is the one that changes the object from a string to an integer.  Which, converted again to a string by the MsgBox() call, produces "0" instead of "00".

Notable is that C# does not permit this and generate a compile error.  This rewriting trick is rather nasty, if the method itself changes the original object then you'll have a very hard time guessing what is going on since that doesn't change the passed argument value.

Answer (score 0):

`ByRef` means that value passes by reference and in function will be used the same value what has been sent.

`ByVal` means that value passes by value (function creates a copy of passed value) and you use only copy of value.